# Ruby Sunspot: how to refactor common code between search do block?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, sunspot

How can I refactor out common code from a Sunspot `search do` block into a method that can then be called from multiple places? I suspect this is perhaps more of a Ruby metaprogramming question than a Sunspot-specific one, but here goes.

I have a model that uses sunspot like so:

```
class Book
  def self.basic_search(params)    
    search do
      # boilerplate...
      facet :category
      paginate page: params[:p], per_page: APP_CONFIG[:results_per_page]

      # bespoke basic_search search code goes here
    end    
  end

  def self.curated_search(params)    
    search do
      # boilerplate...
      facet :category
      paginate page: params[:p], per_page: APP_CONFIG[:results_per_page]

      # bespoke curated_search code goes here
    end    
  end

end
```

Then I try to refactor the code like so:

```
class Book
  def self.basic_search(params)    
    search do
      boilerplate params
      # bespoke basic_search search code goes here
    end    
  end

  def self.curated_search(params)    
    search do
      boilerplate params
      # bespoke curated_search code goes here
    end    
  end

  def self.boilerplate(params)
    facet :category
    paginate page: params[:p], per_page: APP_CONFIG[:results_per_page]
  end

end
```

Since the boilerplate method is defined as a class method on Book, this unsurprisingly results in:

```
undefined method 'boilerplate' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Search:0x007f92b4177a98
```

I suspect that some usage of `instance_eval` is required, but being new to Ruby I'm not quite sure how to apply that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.

```
def self.basic_search(params)    
  search do
    boilerplate(self, params)  # here, self is a sunspot search instance

    # bespoke basic_search search code goes here
  end    
end

def self.curated_search(params)    
  search do
    boilerplate(self, params)  # here, self is a sunspot search instance

    # bespoke curated_search code goes here
  end    
end

def self.boilerplate(sunspot, params)
  sunspot.instance_eval do 
    facet :category
    paginate page: params[:p], per_page: APP_CONFIG[:results_per_page]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the specific issue, try scoping it to call `Book.boilerplate` instead. As the error message suggests, the content inside the `search`'s `do...end` block is evaluated inside `Sunspot::DSL::Search` rather than inside `Book`.

See the following example. Simplified for readability where `Foo` -> `Book` and `Bar` -> `Search`

Original way w/ duplication

```
class Foo
  def self.bar()
    p 1
  end

  def self.baz()
    p 1
  end
end
```

De-duplicated. Note that in the sunspot example, most likely method definition hooks or something comparable is used to define methods on `Book` rather than using the hard-coded pass through here. The point is that `Bar` can call `quux` which is in `Foo`.

```
class Foo
  # Following two methods inserted via DSL magic. #Simplified for readability.
  def self.bar
    Bar.bar
  end

  def self.baz
    Bar.baz
  end

  def self.quux()
    p 1
  end
end

class Bar
  def self.bar
    Foo.quux
  end

  def self.baz
    Foo.quux
  end
end
```

In your particular case, however, this still may not be doing what you want in that the params being evaluated should presumably be evaluated in `Search` and not `Book`. Depending on how `search` does param caching, you should consider trying something like this.

```
def self.boilerplate(params)
  search do
    facet :category
    paginate page: params[:p], per_page: APP_CONFIG[:results_per_page]
  end
end
```